# Phonographic memory?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an aural version of a photographic memory?

I have never encountered the term "*phono*graphic memory". And while photographs are still a thing, phonographs are practically dinosaurs. The word itself feels outdated.

I'm actually looking for a term (idiom or phrase) that means "remembers the exact words that were spoken".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German psychologist [Ulric Nesser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulric_Neisser) coined the term "[echoic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echoic_memory)" for this back in 1967.

Answer (score 3):

Any perfect memory of this nature is actually called an [**eidetic memory**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory).

From the Wikipedia article on eidetic memory

> Scholar Annette Kujawski Taylor stated, "In eidetic memory, a person has an almost faithful mental image snapshot or photograph of an event in their memory. However, eidetic memory is not limited to visual aspects of memory and includes **auditory memories** as well as various sensory aspects across a range of stimuli associated with a visual image." [Emphasis mine]

True *photographic memories* have never truly been shown to exist.  It's the ability to remember strings of seemingly random bits of information without any pattern or detail that binds them together. (*e.g.* pages of random numbers)